# Eclipse JUnit debug mode terminating while paused/without me stepping

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, testing, junit

I've been working with Eclipse for several months without this issue. Suddenly, while I'm trying to debug, Eclipse is skipping ahead and finishing the test without me doing anything. I.E I've got a breakpoint. I press debug, the code runs to the breakpoint. I go to look at variables, etc. or step through a few lines, and after just about 15 seconds consistently, the test just finishes regardless of what I'm doing. So essentially I've gotta speedrun any testing I do to be within 15 seconds, which is getting ridiculous.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the test?

Comment: It's happening in every test I do, including ones that have worked in the past

Comment: Is it happening with all junits or some particular junit? Updating your question with code for a junit for which you faced this issue would help answering the question.